# How to insert mathematical symbols between frame boxes side by side?

Tags: framed

I want to put two frame boxes containing some text side by side and put a mathematical symbol (e.g. a plus sign) in between them. How do I do that? Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item box2-item1
\item box2-item2
\item box2-item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed}

\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item box2-item1
\item box2-item2
\item box2-item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed}
\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item box2-item1
\item box2-item2
\item box2-item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `minipage` instead of `multicols`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item box2-item1
\item box2-item2
\item box2-item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}
$+$
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item box2-item1
\item box2-item2
\item box2-item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}
$+$
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item box2-item1
\item box2-item2
\item box2-item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```